# Omniture form complete tracker currently fires twice

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am currently using Omniture analytics for form tracking. 
when i paste the following text on the button click event on the registration.cshtml page it fires only once which is right.

```
var s = s_gi(s_account);
                s.linkTrackVars = 'prop1,prop8,eVar1,eVar8,events';
                s.prop1 = 'Registration'; s.prop8 = 'Tier 3|Form Complete';
                s.eVar1 = s.prop1;
                s.eVar8 = s.prop8;
                s.linkTrackEvents = 'event2,event8'; s.events = 'event2,event8';
                (s.tl(this, 'o', 'Form Complete'));
```

but this is not the right way since the user can make some mistakes while filling up the form so technically the form is not complete.

I have added this in a javascript function which checks if the form is valid only then it should fire the omniture call. but in doing so it is getting fired twice.

Answer (score 0):

If it's sending two image requests, then that means the function is being called twice, or you have two s.tl functions somewhere.

I would actually recommend sending the data to SiteCatalyst on the registration confirmation page; that way you know for a fact that the data made it to your servers. If there's form info you'd like to send as well, throw it in a query string and use the getQueryParam plugin to take the query string value and pass it as part of the image request.